# .NET Core 2.1 Individual Account Postman Login

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Using Visual Studio 2019, and setting up a new .NET Core 2.1 Project using "Individual User Accounts" everything works great. I can register new users, login with them etc using the built in scaffolding. However... how do I login from Postman or any external method? Where/how can I pass the username/password?

Here is the Startup.cs (mostly default):

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc()
       .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
       {
           options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/About", "RequireAdministratorRole");
           options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Register");
       })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddSingleton<Settings>();
            //services.AddSingleton<Tools>();
            Tools tools = new Tools(Configuration);
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 9;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            // Lockout settings.
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
    }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've now configured your application to use Cookie authentication. It is not a recommended method to use for API apps like in your scenario, you want to login using Postman. Token or JWT authentication is the recommended one. Here is some Microsoft documentation on working with [Single Page Application authentication and authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040)

And by external systems you mean social media providers? You will be able to see the documentation on [configuring social media login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040) in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Thanks. I found a working example for JWT tokens using core 2.1: https://github.com/medhatelmasry/JwtAuthentication and a video explaining it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH4GhmTPf68

Answer (score 0):

> how do I login from Postman or any external method? Where/how can I pass the username/password?

In my understanding you want to directly post username/password to identity for login  ? ASP.NET Core Identity by default prevent cross-site request forgery and you shouldn't directly pass username/password to asp.net core identity for sign in .